# Can I create several foreign key constraints between 2 table?

Tags: database-design

I am trying to build a database of recipes. The problem I am facing is that my recipe book also contains recipes for some of my ingredients (a.k.a. intermediary product) Instead of the following structure:

```
product(
    id VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY NOT_NULL,
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT_NULL,
    description VARCHAR
)
ingredient(
    id VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY NOT_NULL,
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT_NULL,
    description VARCHAR
)
recipe_step(
    step_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT_NULL,
    recipe_id VARCHAR(10) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES product(id)
    ingre_id VARCHAR(10) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ingredient(id)
    amount DECIMAL NOT_NULL
)
```

I wish to keep `product` and `ingredient` in one table. Can I write:

```
product(
    id VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY NOT_NULL,
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT_NULL,
    description VARCHAR
)
recipe_step(
    step_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT_NULL,
    recipe_id VARCHAR(10) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES product(id)
    ingre_id VARCHAR(10) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES product(id)
    amount DECIMAL NOT_NULL
)
```

In `recipe_step` everything is measured in grams.

I am a total newbie in RDBMS. I haven't really decided yet, but I wish to start with something simple. If sqlite won't do, I would probably try MySQL.

Comment: Could you please clarify what is the real world entity of "product"?